# Perl Regex match delimited string

Tags: regex, pcre, netezza

For the life of me I can't figure this out in Perl syntax. I've manged to get this flavour working in Javascript where N is the match number.

```
^(?:[^\|]*\|){N}([^\|]*)
```

I've also tried matching against anything that isn't a pipe, however I just can't seem to write the regex to extract the match index in the Perl flavour that I need. Any pointers?

Data looks like this

> astring| another string|test|maybe some more text

When the first regex runs in the regex debugger it produces this (which is what I'd like to run) .

`^(?:[^\|]*\|){0}([^\|]*) produces 'astring'`
`^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}([^\|]*) produces 'maybe some more text'`

However, when I run it in Netezza (Perl Regex, this is where I need it to run) it  produces:

`^(?:[^\|]*\|){0}([^\|]*) produces 'astring'`
`^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}([^\|]*) produces 'astring| another string|test|maybe some more text'`

UPDATE:
Problem solved the Regex was okay, however was me being a dunce and not using the function in Netezza correctly. This led to a huge over complication of the regex. Example below REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, '[^\|]+',1 ,4 )

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: if I try your regex, i get what you want in the capturing group, what's the problem then? https://regex101.com/r/w2V2sK/1

Comment: apologies if that wasn't clear. I've updated my question

Comment: Still don't get where the problem is, the part you want is still stored is the first capturing group. You should be able to get what you want, stored into the variable $1. click on the link in my previous commentary if you don't get what i'm saying ;)

Comment: Maybe it's just how I'm running the query

Comment: What's wrong with `split`?

Comment: Sorry cut off what i was writing. Maybe it's the way I'm writing the query. I'm running `REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, '^(?:[^\|]*\|){3}([^\|]*)')` and it's returning `astring| another string|test|maybe some more text` instead of 'maybe some more text'. I can't use split as that function breaks my whole SQL query when there aren't enough delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could repeat the `[^\|]` 1 or more times `[^\|]+`.

`^(?:[^\|]+\|){N}([^\|]+)`

[`^(?:[^\|]+\|){0}([^\|]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KFxkXm/2) would capture `astring` in group 1.

[`^(?:[^\|]+\|){3}([^\|]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KFxkXm/1/) would capture `maybe some more text` in group 1.

Comment: When I run ^(?:[^\|]+\|){0}([^\|]+) it does return astring. However when I change N to 3 it returns the whole string 'astring| another string|test|maybe some more text'. Is it possible it could just be the Perl engine?

Comment: Did you check the first capturing group?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that please?

Comment: The last part in your regex `([^\|]+)` uses parenthesis to capture  your value in a group. You might check for example [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) about grouping and capturing. If you use {0}, the full match is "astring" and that is  the same as group 1, if you use {3}, the full match is the whole senctence, and the value in group 1 is "maybe some more text". If you click on the example links, you can see that what is highlighted in blue is the full match, and what is highlighted in green is the first captured group.

Comment: Problem solved the Regex was okay, however was me being a dunce and not using the function in Netezza correctly. This led to a huge over complication of the regex. Example below REGEXP_EXTRACT(column, '[^\|]+',1 ,4 )

Answer (score 0):

When your data is delimited, the tool you want is not a magic regex, but a split:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $target_field = 3;
my $str = "astring| another string|test|maybe some more text";

print +(split (/\|/, $str))[$target_field]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's the Perl flavour of regex sitting underneath Netezza, no Perl itself.

Comment: So not in fact a perl question then?